# Как настроить vs code для работы с sass(не конвертор!)

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass

Подскажите пожалуйста, как `настроить Visual Studio Code` для работы с `Sass`. Мне ***не нужно конвертировать код***, а именно подсказки как в стоке с `Css`, подсветка синтаксиса и тд. Пробовал плагин "`Sass (.sass only)`" но он, почему то, не работает. Также установлен "`Sass Formatter`"

Конвертирую с помощью "`Prepros`"

Answer (score 0):

`Sass` (`.sass only`) прекрасно работает, просто нужно было переключить на нужный синтаксис в нижней панели: по умолчанию там стоит `css`. Выбираешь `sass` и весь синтаксис подсвечивается и работают подсказки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]